# Techniques for cooking beef shin in the piece

Tags: beef, slow-cooking

I have a large (1.5kg/3lb) piece of beef shin, in the piece with skin on. I normally use beef shin for stews, but I would like to try slow-roasting or pot roasting it in a single piece.

Have you tried this? Can you recommend any techniques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used beef shin, but it's probably a good candidate for braising. Brown the outside in a pan, add aromatics (carrot, onion, celery, herbs) and beef stock, cover and let gently simmer for about 3 hours or so, until it starts to fall apart.

Once it's done, you can separate it from the juice and reduce the braising juices to a sauce that you can serve it with (you might add a bit of cornstarch slurry or a roux if you want to thicken the sauce more).

This basic technique works well for types of meat that have a lot of connective tissue.